# Euler totient function and unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. A clarification.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm studying the construction of unramified extensions, and [many references](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/appendix2.pdf) say that it's enough to attach the $p^n-1$ primitive root of unity to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in order to obtain the unique degree $n$ unramified extension of the $p$-adics.

What I don't understand, is why the minimal polynomial of it, so a cyclotomic polynomial, has degree $n$. I'd say that the cyclotomic polynomial has degree $\phi(p^n-1)$, but $\phi(p^n-1)\neq n$ in general.

So where I'm overlooking something?

Comment: Well, take $n=1$... In that case, the residue field   $\mathbb F_p$ contains all the roots of $x^{p-1}-1 = 0$; hence the polynomial factors completely in $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't get the meaning of both comments. What is a primitive root of $n$? If you mean order $n$ I'm aware I'm attaching a primitive root of order $p^n-1$ and not $n$.

Comment: Sorry I meant it doesn't say to add a primitive $n$th root of one, it say specifically to add "a primitive root of order $p^n-1$".  So I am guessing a factor of $x^{p^n-1}-1$ that has degree $n$.  Does that make more sense now?

Comment: and I guess this is different from what I intend. So a primitive root of order $p^n-1$ what is supposed to be? a Generator of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Comment: The finite field $k=\mathbb F_{p^n}$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^n-1} -1$ - it is  the extension of degree $n$ over $\mathbb F_p$ (and the finite field $k$ is the residue field of the corresponding unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$).

Comment: In fact did you read the proof in that document you link to?  I think it's clarified pretty well in the proof what exactly they're talking about.

Comment: @GregoryGrant yes and in fact the point of my question is that I was (mis)reading primitive roots of unity everywhere, that's why I was confused.

Comment: @LuigiM Cool, I think you have it straightened out now.  Which brings us to the final problem.  How do we post an official answer so this question can be removed from the queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document says to add a "primitive root of order $p^n-1$" not a "primitive $n$-th root of one".  So it must be an irreducible factor of $x^{p^n-1}-1$ that has degree $n$, but not $x^n-1$.

Comment: Right, so a root of $x^{p^n-1}-1$.  If it said of order $n$ then it would be a root of $x^n-1$.

Comment: Oops, where did your comment go?  I guess you figured it out.

Comment: Ok I'm totally confused by the notation now. Let me explain what's unclear to me: I agree that I'm attaching a primitive root of order $p^n-1$. this means $\xi$ (the primitive root) is a root of the $p^n-1$ cyclotomic polynomial, by definition. So the degree of the extension should be equal to the degree of the polynomial, (because it is irreducible) and therefore I' confused because one is $\phi(p^n-1)$ and the other is $n$. So the only possibility is that the cyclotomic polynomial is no more irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $\xi$ is a root of a $n$-degree irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Is that the case?

Comment: That's right, $\xi$ is the root of an irreducible factor of $x^{p^n-1}-1$ and that irreducible factor has to have degree $n$.

Comment: Right, sorry now I am confusing terminology, so I'll fix my last comment.

Comment: Ok now everything makes sense. I'll accept the answer in order to conclude this question. Thank you very much for your patience and explanations!

Comment: No problem, it's a beautiful topic.  :-)

Comment: You seem to confusing irreducibility over $\Bbb Q$ (as applies, for instance to the cyclotomic polynomials) with irreducibility over $\Bbb Q_p$. For instance, $\Phi_4(X)=X^2+1$ is $\Bbb Q$-irreducible but factors into linears as a $\Bbb Q_5$-polynomial.

Comment: Right the factor of degree $n$ has to be irreducible over $\Bbb Q_p$.